Isn't every algorithm technically ω(0)?
Isn't every function is ω(0)?
From my understanding, ω (little omega) notation is used as a strict lower bound for any function. Since no function can run in less than 0 "time" then ω(0) must be a valid strict lower bound for every function.
From my understanding is like saying x^2=O(x^3), which is technically right.
I know that this isn't useful as ω(0) doesn't help us at all describe the answer, but isn't it technically right to say that every function is ω(0).
I searched on the internet and didn't find anything, and when asking chatGPT it just told me I was wrong, and didn't address my point directly.

Even if it's technically true, it seems utterly unuseful.

@wohlstad I know this is useless, but I wanted to check my understanding about it. What confused me was that every "AI" told me I was wrong and couldn't be convinced otherwise. I know they are not good at reasoning, but when confronted with a mistake they usually acknowledge it, and them not doing so made me think I was the one in the wrong.

Then you might understand why Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned here.

Generally tight bounds are what are used with these notations.

@RiccardoPiana just for fun I asked ChatGPT: "Isn't every algorithm technically ω(0)?", and in the response the summary is: "Every algorithm that has a non-zero running time for increasing n is technically ω(0), because it eventually grows faster than a function that is always zero.". So sometimes ChatGPT gets it right ;-)

Some people define f(n) = ω(g(n)) as meaning that lim_{n -> ∞} f(n)/g(n) = ∞.  Under that definition, ω(0) has no meaning since you can't divide by zero.

@NateEldredge as far as I know the formal definition is the one that really counts, please see my answer.


Isn't every function is ω(0)?

Since we are measuring execution time of algorithms, we can assume that the functions f that are interesting are non-zero and positive ones.
Under that assumption: yes it is true that every such function f ∈ ω(0).
The formal definition for ω notation is:

f(n) ∈ ω(g(n)) if and only if:    for all k>0, there exists n0, such
that for all n>n0 : f(n)>k*g(n).

Our g(n) is 0.
For every k>0 we can choose e.g. n0=0, and then we will have:
f(n) > k*g(n) for every n>0 (because k*g(n) is k*0 which is 0, and f is assumed to be positive).
I.e. our positive f satisfies the definition to be ∈ ω(0).
Having said all that, I don't any case where this analysis is actually useful.
